# Does the equation $\sigma(\sigma(x^2))=2x\sigma(x)$ have any odd solutions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, conjectures, divisors-multiples, arithmetic-functions

This question was posted in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3779447) in early August 2020.  It did garner several upvotes, but did not receive any responses.  I have therefore cross-posted it here, hoping that it gets answered.

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the classical *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

Here is my question:

> Does the equation $\sigma(\sigma(x^2))=2x\sigma(x)$ have any odd solutions?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried searching for solutions to the equation in [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/), in the range $1 < x \leq {10}^6$, here is the **Pari-GP** code:

```
for(x=1, 1000000, if(sigma(sigma(x^2))==2*x*sigma(x),print(x,factor(x))))
```

Here are the results:

```
9516[2, 2; 3, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1]
380640[2, 5; 3, 1; 5, 1; 13, 1; 61, 1]
```

Note that both results obtained $x_1 = 9516$ and $x_2 = 380640$ are even.

The **Pari-GP interpreter** of Sage Cell Server crashes as soon as a search limit of ${10}^7$ is specified.

**CONJECTURE**

> The equation $\sigma(\sigma(x^2)) = 2x\sigma(x)$ does not have any odd solutions.

Alas, I have no proof.

**SOME PARTIAL RESULTS**

Per Will Jagy's answer (and a subsequent comment by Erick Wong) to the following [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1097803), we have the *conjectured* (sharp?) upper bound
$$\frac{\sigma(x^2)}{x\sigma(x)} \leq \prod_{\rho}{\frac{{\rho}^2 + \rho + 1}{{\rho}^2 + \rho}} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(3)}.$$

*Claim:* $\sigma(x^2) \neq p^r$ if prime $p \geq 5$.

Suppose to the contrary that the equation $\sigma(\sigma(x^2))=2x\sigma(x)$ has an odd solution, and that  $\sigma(x^2) = p^r$ for some prime $p \geq 5$.

Then we have
$$\frac{\sigma(p^r)}{p^r}=\frac{\sigma(\sigma(x^2))}{\sigma(x^2)}=\frac{2x\sigma(x)}{\sigma(x^2)} \geq \frac{2\zeta(3)}{\zeta(2)} \approx 1.4615259388.$$
But we know that the *abundancy index* $\sigma(p^r)/p^r$ is bounded above by
$$\frac{\sigma(p^r)}{p^r} < \frac{p}{p - 1} \leq \frac{5}{4}.$$
This is a contradiction.

*Claim:* $\sigma(x^2) \neq p^r q^s$ if primes $p \geq 5$ and $q \geq 7$.

Suppose to the contrary that the equation $\sigma(\sigma(x^2))=2x\sigma(x)$ has an odd solution, and that  $\sigma(x^2) = p^r q^s$ for some primes $p \geq 5$ and $q \geq 7$.

Then we have
$$\frac{\sigma(p^r)}{p^r}\cdot\frac{\sigma(q^s)}{q^s}=\frac{\sigma(\sigma(x^2))}{\sigma(x^2)}=\frac{2x\sigma(x)}{\sigma(x^2)} \geq \frac{2\zeta(3)}{\zeta(2)} \approx 1.4615259388.$$
But we know that the *product of abundancy indices* $(\sigma(p^r)/p^r)(\sigma(q^s)/q^s)$ is bounded above by
$$\frac{\sigma(p^r)}{p^r}\cdot\frac{\sigma(q^s)}{q^s} < \frac{p}{p - 1}\cdot\frac{q}{q - 1} \leq \frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{7}{6} = \frac{35}{24} = 1.458\overline{333}.$$
This is a contradiction.

*Edit (August 27, 2020 - 4:21 PM Manila time)*

**MOTIVATION FOR THE PROBLEM**

[Slowak (1999)](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/128884/MathSlov_49-1999-3_3.pdf) proved that an odd perfect number $N = u^t v^2$ (with special prime $u$ satisfying $u \equiv t \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(u,v)=1$) must be of the form
$$\frac{u^t \sigma(u^t)}{2}\cdot{d},$$
where $d > 1$.

[Dris (2017)](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) showed further that $d$ must have the form
$$\frac{D(v^2)}{\sigma(u^{t-1})}=\gcd(v^2,\sigma(v^2))=\frac{\sigma(v^2)}{u^t}=\frac{v^2}{\sigma(u^t)/2},$$
where $D(y)=2y-\sigma(y)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $y$.

If the odd perfect number $N = u^t v^2$ is of the form
$$\frac{u^t \sigma(u^t)}{2}\cdot{v},$$
then by the results of Slowak and Dris, we have the equations
$$\sigma(v^2) = u^t v$$
and
$$2v = \sigma(u^t),$$
which led me to my question in this post.

Comment: Note that $\sigma(x^2)$ is deficient, if the equation $$\sigma(\sigma(x^2))=2x\sigma(x)$$
holds.

Comment: Just to know: Does this come from odd perfect number conjecture?

Comment: @C.F.G: Yes, this problem does stem from considerations involving the odd perfect number conjecture.

Comment: @C.F.G:  I have edited my question to add the specific motivation for my original problem.

Comment: May I know why this question was downvoted as well? Some form of feedback, hopefully constructive, would go a long way towards improving future questions/posts.  As it is, I am totally clueless.

Comment: Just by brute force with applying gp directly: The only solutions until $x=10000000$ are $x_1$ and $x_2$. I'm now trying the range until $x=100000000$.

Comment: Even below $x = 10^8$ there is no additional solution. Now I'll try the range until $x = 10^9$.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, @DieterKadelka!  If I may just ask, how much time did it take to test the range ${10}^7 \leq x \leq {10}^8$ on your computer?

Comment: About 1-2 hours, I did not measure the time exactly. My system is linux with 3,6 GHz and gp/pari from the pari group. If you access to a development system I would install gp/pari.

Comment: Just checking, @DieterKadelka:  Did you find any additional solutions to the equation in the range ${10}^8 \leq x \leq {10}^9$, apart from $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: I had to stop my calculations above $x = 8 \cdot 10^8$ (I used my computer otherwise). Until then there have be no new solutions.  I doubt if you find any solutions with this technique.

Comment: Thank you for the update, @DieterKadelka!  I will take it from here.  =)

Comment: There are no other solutions below $10^{10}$.