# On odd perfect numbers and a GCD - Part II

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

(Note:  A detailed version of this question was posted in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3626486) last April 15, 2020.  It has not received any responses there as of yet.  I have therefore cross-posted it here, hoping that it is suitable for this site (i.e. that it is research-level) and that it can get answered here.)

My primary aim with pursuing this question has been to resolve the problem as described in this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3738458).  Note that comments below this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/370047) show that there are no odd solutions below ${10}^{10}$ to the closely related equation
$$\sigma(\sigma(x^2))=2x\sigma(x)$$
where $\sigma=\sigma_1$ is the classical sum of divisors.

So now, let $m = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Since
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}$$
we obtain
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
if and only if $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$.  This latter condition holds, for example, when $\sigma(n^2)=q^k n$.

Now the GCD
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
can be easily expressed in terms of a linear combination of $n^2$ and $\sigma(n^2)$, via
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2-\sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}$$
yielding
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=2(1-q)n^2 + q\sigma(n^2).$$

Here is my question:

> How can I then derive a linear combination for $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))$ in terms of $\sigma(q^k)$ and $\sigma(n^2)$?  Note that this should always be (*unconditionally*) possible by [Bézout's Identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezoutsIdentity.html).

I tried using the equation
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(m)=2m=2q^k n^2$$
but since $\sigma(q^k)$ and $\sigma(n^2)$ are *on the same side of the equation*, I guess this does not lead anywhere?

Comment: " I guess this does not lead anywhere?" Yes, it does not.

Comment: If $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, then it is easy to show that
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

I just do not know if this will count as a(n) (integral) linear combination formula for $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))$ (in terms of $\sigma(q^k)$ and $\sigma(n^2)$), similar to the integral, linear combination formula for $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$ as given in the original post.

Comment: To determine if $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, it [suffices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341685) to check whether $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is **squarefree**.